# Python: Celery inspect

Tags: python, celery

I found some related questions but nothing that describes exactly my problem. So I can inspect my queue with a code like that:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
#inspect(['my_queue']), with a list instead of a str, should work! 
i = inspect(['my_queue'])
print(i.active())  #  get a list of active tasks
print(i.registered()) # get a list of tasks registered
print(i.scheduled()) # get a list of tasks waiting
print(i.reserved()) #tasks that has been received, but waiting to be executed
```

But somehow, for every second execution the method returns a empty task list. Sometimes I also get a Reset Connection Error. Some ideas why this happes? Is there something like a interval, where workers fill there active tasks list or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the code you wrote above is not how the actual application looks (it can't work without a Celery object). - The only explanation is that you have some connectivity issues, otherwise it should work every time you run, unless genuinely there are no tasks to report. In other words - the cluster is idle.

Keep in mind that inspect broadcasts a message to all the workers and waits for their replies. If some of them times out for whatever reason(s), you will not see that worker in the output. If it happens that only that worker was busy, you may end up with an empty list of tasks.

Try to call something like `celery -A yourproject.celeryapp status` to see if your workers are responsive, and if everything is OK run your script. - It should work.

Comment: I think i now know what the problem was. I have two queues. For each queue i started one seperate worker. But i named them both with the flag  -n "someName" when i started them. When i now inspect it with "someName" as inspect arghument, it sometimes found one of the queues and the other time the orher, which had no tasks at the moment. Is it correct that this name has to be unique for each queue?. I started them one a remote server and thought it could be a way to identify the remote server somehow later.

Comment: You do not have to specify the queue name in the inspect() calls - it will give you information about all the queues then. As a matter of fact, I never specify the queue name(s) in my inspect() calls...